# Capistrano's Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

It is the first time I use Capistrano and the application had been already published without it. When I type cap deploy:migrations I get the following error after some successful commands:

```
  * executing "cd /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/releases/20090818111104; rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["foto-fiori.com"]
    [foto-fiori.com] executing command
 ** [out :: foto-fiori.com] (in /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/releases/20090818111104)
 ** [out :: foto-fiori.com] Missing the Rails 2.3.3 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.3 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
    command finished
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/releases/20090818111104; rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on foto-fiori.com
```

I tried to comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION from environment.rb, but is the same.

I also typed the last commands manually:

```
$ cd /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/releases/20090818111104
$ rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate
(in /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/releases/20090818111104)
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/releases/20090818111104/config/database.yml
/home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/releases/20090818111104/Rakefile:10
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ** [out :: foto-fiori.com] Missing the Rails 2.3.3 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.3 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

Your problem is right in there.  You need to install Rails 2.3.3.

It also looks like you're missing your `database.yml` file, and I'm assuming that's just something source control missed?

Comment: Don't put database.yml in your source control. You should have it in you #{shared_path}/config and you copy it over it your config directory using after deploy:update_code hook in your deploy.rb

Putting this file in source control is a security risk.